# Is there a specific algorithm for generating all combinations of n elements, taken n-1 at a Time

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I know of the algorithm for the general case (e.g. generating all combination of 
n elements taken m at a time) but I was wondering if there was a faster one specifically 
designed for the case m=n-1. Also, if such an algorithm exists, could anyone point to
 a C/C++ implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty easy - iterate over all the elements using a simple cycle. In this cycle construct a new set consisting of all elements but one(the one pointing to by the index in the cycle).

NOTE: a few notes so that you can achieve `O(N)` complexity(I will use `C++` for example but you may use any other language with vector-like container).

In `C++`: asssuming you have an `vector<int> a` that holds all the numbers:

```
vector<int> a;
... initialize a ....
vector<int> b(a.begin()+1, a.size()); // Now b will have all elements of a but the first one.

for (int i=0;i<a.size() - 1;++i) {
  b.push_back(a[i]);
  swap(b[i], b[b.size()-1]);
  b.pop_back();
}
```

Using the code above b will sequentally iterate over all the combinations.

Comment: Can also explain the time complexity. Am assuming we will have to iterate through 'n' elements 'n' times. hence complexity will be O(n to the power n). Am i right?

Comment: @sonic: suppose n=5 so S={1,2,3,4,5} and S*_{0},...S*_{5} are the 5 possible subsets. Declare P[5] an empty array of length 5. Copy S in P. For each value of i in 1->5 do: permute P[i] and P[5]. Pick S_*{i}=P[0:4] (the first n-1 entries of P). End for.

Comment: @user189035 : yup. i got that. can you explain the complexity in terms of n?

Comment: @sonic I believe that if you implement the algorithm in the best possible way you can iterate over the n possible sets in O(n) which of course is the best possible.

Answer (score 0):

if a set has

- 2 Elements {1,2}   subset will have 2^2 elements {},{1},{2},{1,2}
- 3 elements {1,2,3} subset will have 2^3  elements {},
  {1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}
- 4 elements {1,2,3,4} subset will have 2^4  elements {},
  {1},{2},{3},{4},{1,2},{1,3},
  {1,4}{2,3},{2,4},{3,4},{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,3,4},{2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}

So i think above set could be achieved using 2 loops

also in **Combinations**

Let U be a set with n elements; we want to count the number of distinct subsets of the set U that have exactly j elements. this could be written as  N!/J! *(N-J)!

note: empty element subset can be removed and formula becomes 2^n-1

Here is my answer , if at all this helps

- if N=2 {1},{2}
- for N=3  add 3 at the end of N=2 elements {1,3}{2,3} and mix N=2
  elements {1,2}
- for N=4 add 4 at the end of N=3 elements {1,3,4}{2,3,4} {1,2,4} and
  Mix N=3 elements {1,2,3}

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your notation, but this set has $n$ elements and can be computed at time $O(n)$ ($O(1)$ for each component) following Ivaylo Strandjev's strategy.

Comment: will this link helps ? - http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/generating-subsets.shtml

Comment: @simplercoder: thanks now I can understand your proposal, which solves the general problem. But i'm only interested in the much simpler case of when J=N-1...

Comment: i think the catch is J=N-1 what does this means to you ? can you give an example. what i thought is if you solve a problem for N the same solution is for N-1 or N+1  . Are you looking for O(N) solution ?

Comment: I see what you mean from the above comment you are only interested for N-1 set right ? so if there is 4 elements you are only interested for sets of 3 ?

Comment: so for 3 elements {1,2},{1,3},{2,3} for 4 elements {1,2,3}{1,2,4}{1,3,4}{2,3,4} for 5 elements {1,2,3,4}{1,2,3,5}{1,2,4,5}{1,3,4,5}{2,3,4,5} . If you see N=5 is actually {N=4 + add element 5 at end} + {1235}. So i guess we can divide it into sub problems and can Achieve NLogn(N) complexity. Hope this helps !!

Comment: @simplercode: yes, this is the algorithm Ivaylo Strandjev proposed. It is O(n)...*Not* nlogn.

Comment: I am sorry in beginning I could not understand Ivaylo's solution . actually to be honest the solution clicked to me - quite a while later.